# Cannot attach the .mdf file in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem when attaching an .mdf file in sql server 2012. When I add an .mdf for my database it gives me the error below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. Did you - ah - READ the error?

The part where it says "Access Denied" and "whle attempting to open or create the physical file".

What you think SQL Server can do when SQL Server is not allowed to read the file?

Check file and directory permissions and - start, please- READING the error. THis one is extremely clear.

Comment: In case the user that lacks permission is unclear, the OP could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to identify the user account, which should be the account being used to run the SQL Server service.

Comment: So how to change the permission i am pretty new in deploying an application?

Comment: Learn how to use windows? This is end user stuff. Hint: Check the properties of files and folders, there you find security settings.